# xslt replace a string

Tags: xslt, replace

working with xslt 1.0 im trying to replace the char " : " for an space, before this i need to ignore the characters before the first occurrence of ":". Example:

Having :
07:090126:00006591:::

I want to get.

090126 00006591.

Im trying with this two templates but im not able to acheive it.

```
<xsl:param name="requestor"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($requestor,':')" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select=':' />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select=' ' />

        </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>






<xsl:template name="string-replace">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:param name="replace" />
<xsl:param name="with" />

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$with" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$replace)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Could anybody help?

This lines does not work:

```
<xsl:with-param name="replace" select=':' />
<xsl:with-param name="with" select=' ' />
```

Regards1!

Comment: To replace a certain single character with another single character the use of `translate(substring-after($requestor, ':'), ':' , ' ')` should do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delimiters around string literals:

```
<xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
  <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($requestor,':')" />
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="':'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="' '" />

</xsl:call-template>
```